# calc(100vh - x rem/px) => Footer and padding not working for me to stick to Footer to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 main screens, 2 of them have content enough to need a scrollBar on the Y axis, but not on the other 2. I can't use absolute/fixed, bottom: 0 to stick it ⇾ The footer will always be seen and would not fit the design... And using height:100vh leads to unnecessary scrollbar, so I did this: height: calc(100vh - 5.5rem) [2rem from paddingY on footer and 3rem from paddingTop on Container Component]. Even tho it looks fine on my computer, it breaks on my companion Screen which is smaller. Here's some Pictures and code:
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
<template>
  <section class="px-8 bg-white overflow-hidden pt-20 mainDicLayout">
    <div class="max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-16 mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-16 gap-y-8 lg:grid-cols-5">
        <div class="lg:py-12 lg:col-span-2">
          <p class="max-w-xl text-5xl font-semibold">{{ t('questions') }}</p>

          <div class="mt-8">
            <p class="my-12 not-italic text-lg text-secondary">
              {{ t('questionsDesc') }}
            </p>
            <!-- <div class="w-full  border-t-accent"></div> -->
            <hr class="text-pink w-1/2" />
            <div class="my-4">
              <!-- <p class="mt-2 not-italic text-lg text-secondary leading-3">
                Contact us
              </p> -->
              <a
                style="color: #2b96ee"
                class="font-bold underline cursor-pointer"
                href="mailto:support@redpadel.com"
                >support@redpadel.com</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex gap-6 flex-start my-6">
            <div>
              <a
                href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/redpadel/about/?viewAsMember=true"
              >
                <img
                  :src="require('../assets/svg/linkedin.svg')"
                  alt="linkedIn-logo"
                  class="h-14"
                />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/redpadelofficial/">
                <img
                  :src="require('../assets/svg/Instagram.svg')"
                  alt="instagram-logo"
                  class="h-14"
                />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bg-white lg:p-12 lg:col-span-3">
          <form @submit="sendContact" class="space-y-7 max-w-xl">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-7 sm:grid-cols-2">
              <input
                class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 sm:col-span-1 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
                type="text"
                :placeholder="t('contact.firstName')"
                v-model="firstName"
                required
              />
              <input
                class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 sm:col-span-1 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
                type="text"
                :placeholder="t('contact.lastName')"
                v-model="lastName"
                required
              />
              <select
                class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
                required
                v-model="purpose"
              >
                <option disabled value="" class="bg-disabled">
                  {{ t('contact.purpose') }}
                </option>
                <option
                  v-for="option in purposeOptions"
                  :key="option.value"
                  :value="option.value"
                >
                  {{ t(option.text) }}
                </option>
              </select>
              <input
                class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
                type="email"
                :placeholder="t('contact.email')"
                v-model="email"
                @click="focused = true"
                required
                pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
              />
              <span v-if="focused" class="triggerError"
                >It should be a valid email address!</span
              >

              <input
                class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
                type="text"
                :placeholder="t('contact.subject')"
                v-model="subject"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div>
              <label class="sr-only" for="message">{{
                t('contact.message')
              }}</label>
              <textarea
                class="w-full p-3 text-sm border-disabled rounded-lg focus:ring-0 focus:outline-none focus:border-pink"
                :placeholder="t('contact.message')"
                rows="8"
                id="message"
                v-model="message"
                required
              ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
              <button
                type="submit"
                class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-full px-5 py-3 text-white bg-accent rounded-lg sm:w-auto"
              >
                <span class="font-medium bg-accent"> {{ t('submit') }} </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<style>
.mainDicLayout {
  height: calc(100vh - 5.5rem);
}
</style>
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to use `min-height` rather than `height`, as you want the footer to be stuck to the bottom unless the y content is greater than the viewport height. I may be misunderstanding your issue though.

Comment: if I use min-height: 100vh => It still generates the scroll bar. Do you mean to do min-height: calc( 100vh - 5.5 rem)?

Comment: Whatever min height will give your document a total height of 100vh will not generate a scrollbar.

Comment: Already did it and it works, thanxs Alex!